# How to set distinct variables for different hosts in an external variables yaml to be used in Ansible? variables

Tags: linux, ansible

I have for example this playbook:

```
- name: System Configuration
  hosts: host1, host2
  become: yes
  tasks: 
    - name: Set current app version
      shell: export APP_VERSION={{ app_version|quote }}
```

I wish to set this variables for multiple hosts, for example `host` and `host2`. I read somewhere that I can create a `yml` file with the name of each host and store the variables fort each host there  but I cane find how to load this file for each host.

I thought it may be loaded automatically if the name matches the host name but I dont think this happens I get an error `FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable`

so how can I define a set for variables for each host separately?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options.

1. For example, create a dictionary in **'*group_vars/all*'**

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all 
app_versions:
  host1: '1.1'
  host2: '1.2'
  default: '1.0'
app_version: "{{ app_versions[inventory_hostname]|
                 default(app_versions.default) }}"
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: app_version
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [host3] => 
  app_version: '1.0'
ok: [host1] => 
  app_version: '1.1'
ok: [host2] => 
  app_version: '1.2'
```

---

2. The next option is **'*vars_files*'**. Create a YAML file and use it in the playbook. For example, the file and the playbook give the same result

```yaml
shell> cat app_versions.yml
app_versions:
  host1: '1.1'
  host2: '1.2'
  default: '1.0'
app_version: "{{ app_versions[inventory_hostname]|
                 default(app_versions.default) }}"
```

```yaml
- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  vars_files:
    - app_versions.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: app_version
```

---

3. The next option is to create files in *host_vars*. For example, the **'*host_vars*'** and the playbook give also the same result

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host1.yml 
app_version: '1.1'
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host2.yml 
app_version: '1.2'
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host3.yml 
app_version: '1.0'
```

```yaml
- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: app_version
```

---

The options override each other. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). In the above options, the lowest precedence (4,5) are *group_vars/all* followed by *host_vars* precedence (9,10). The highest precedence (14) has the play *vars_file*.

---

Putting it all together, you might want to put the defaults to the *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
app_versions:
  default: '1.0'
```

and override the defaults in *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> tree host_vars
host_vars
├── host1.yml
└── host2.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host1.yml 
app_version: '1.1'
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host2.yml 
app_version: '1.2'
```

Then, the playbook below gives again the same result

```yaml
- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        app_version: "{{ app_version|
                         default(app_versions[inventory_hostname])|
                         default(app_versions.default) }}"
    - debug:
        var: app_version
```

Comment: thanks that is ok but I found one that I prefer more, creating yml files for each host in the `vars` directory

Comment: You'll be better off putting them into the *host_vars* if you want to create a file for each host. In this case, it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: ah great thanks I will do that

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are probably many solutions to this but the one I liked an used is to create a `vars` sub-directory in my project folder. Ansible look there by default when trying to find variable files for a host with the `include_vars` module.

So in my tasks I added this task:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Load variables for host
      include_vars: 
        file: "{{ inventory_hostname }}.yml"
```

and in my project in the `vars` directory I added a `host_name_as_in_inventory.yml` file with the host-name for each host I want to specify variables for.

---

**Edit:** as it is suggested int he other coment if the `yml` files with the hostnames are added in a directory calles `host_vars` they are loaded automatically so the `include_vars` taks is redundant.